# Rails Active Record multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, associations

I have a Rails app using Postgres and Active Record, and can't fathom the most efficient Associations between my models.

I have a Model called Article.  Article needs to have a **Format** and 2/3 **Genres.**

I need articles to be able to be listed by format i.e.  http://myapp.com/format/format-id/article-id

I also need articles to be listed by genre, so:  myapp.com/genre/genre-name/article-id

I was thinking the Genres and Formats would be models themselves with has_many_and_belongs_to associations to Articles.  Each article has multiple Genres, and 1 format, but each Genre has multiple articles.

I know this should be simple, but I can't find the most efficient route of making this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an old Railscasts episode that goes through the two ways to do many-to-many associations with Rails - you should watch it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many. It's old but mostly still relevant.

So, you've got Articles, Formats, and Genres. Since each Article will have only one Format, you don't need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship there. Article `belongs_to` Format, and Format `has_many` articles.

Each row in the articles table will have a `format_id` field to indicate which Format it belongs to.

The relationship between Genres and Articles is a many-to-many, which is a bit trickier. At the database level, this requires a 'join table'. Your join table would be called something like `articles_genres`, and each row represents one genre that one particular article has. So, it'd have a `genre_id` column, and an `article_id` column.

In terms of rails, there are two ways to do this:

1. Give the `articles_genres` table it's own model. In this case you might want to also give the table a different name, to indicate it's a Model in it's own right, not just a join table. You could call it something like `genreizations`
   or
2. Don't give `articles_genres` table it's own model, and let rails handle it all.

I generally prefer the first way - I feel more in control, and it leaves things more flexible for future. But, either will work. The railscasts episode I linked to describes both ways.

If you go the first way, this is what models you'll have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genreizations
  has_many :genres, through: :genreizations
  belongs_to :format
end

class Format < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Genreization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :genre
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genreizations
  has_many :articles, through: :genreizations
end
```

And in the second way, this is what models you'll have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
  belongs_to :format
end

class Format < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!  I think I will choose the 1st route, to ease the load on Rails.  Thanks again!

Comment: I forgot to mention, the Articles also belong to a User.  Does this need to be a Polymorphic association between Article & User and Format & User?

Comment: Nope. If an article also belongs to a user, then you just have: `belongs_to :user` in your Article model, and `has_many: Article` in your User model. Formats don't need to be involved in that association at all.

Comment: You can have multiple 'belongs_to' associations for a single model, no probelm.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  One last question - in what format / how am I applying genres to articles now?  Would it be an Array of Genre strings?  Or an array of Genre_id's?  I understand the relationships / schemas but can't see how Genre's are now assigned to Articles.